# Redux and immutable js, I lost my state after trying to use immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

After starting my development with reactjs and redux I was thinking that it would be better to work with immutable.js while using redux.

But... Maybe am I retarded or one need some practice before using it properly, everything crashed.

And if you can help understand what's wrong here, it would be awesome!

So, here was my first code:

```
export function posts(state = {
  isFetching: true,
  didInvalidate: false,
  items: []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_REQ:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            didInvalidate: true
        });
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true,
            didInvalidate: false
        });
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false,
            didInvalidate: false,
            items: action.posts
        });
    default:
      return state;
  };
};
```

That I transformed this way:

```
const initPostState = Map({
  isFetching: true,
  didInvalidate: false,
  items: []
});
export function posts(state = initPostState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_REQ:
      return state.set('didInvalidate', true);
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return state.set({
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      });
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return state.set({
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts
      });
    default:
      return state;
  };
};
```

And my container MapStateToProps:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {
    posts: isFetching,
    posts
  } = state.posts;

  console.log(state);
 ...
```

So the problem is, how do I access my states?
The console of state report that:

[image]

I'm lost! Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `get` method from [immutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Use `state.get('didInvalidate')` to access the value of `didInvalidate`, similarly for other values.

If you're using a javascript object, then you can get it like `state.get('something').toJS()`

Doing this should give you the idea

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  const isFetching = state.get('isFetching'),
  const items = state.get('items').toJS();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It "works", except that I have this error:
`state.set` isn't a function, from those lines:
`return state.set({ ...` Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, as all my state aren't using immutable yet, I think it lost its Map state while rendering a page.

Answer (score 3):

Never use `toJS()` in `mapStateToProps`. From the Redux docs:

> Converting an Immutable.JS object to a JavaScript object using `toJS()` will return a new object every time. If you do this in `mapSateToProps`, you will cause the component to believe that the object has changed every time the state tree changes, and so trigger an unnecessary re-render.

If your app requires high performance, you have to use Immutable.js in your Dumb components with their `get()` and `getIn()` helpers.

> Also since ImmutableJS has versatile API, in most cases it removes the
>   need for helper libraries like lodash.

But it mosts cases, you can use the code they proposed to separate Immutable.js from your components by sacrificing performance.

A HOC component (with the latest immutable.js using the isIterable predicate):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Iterable } from 'immutable';

export const toJS = (WrappedComponent) =>
   (wrappedComponentProps) => {
       const KEY = 0;
       const VALUE = 1;

       const propsJS = Object.entries(wrappedComponentProps)
            .reduce((newProps, wrappedComponentProp)  => {
                newProps[wrappedComponentProp[KEY]] = 
                    Iterable.isIterable(wrappedComponentProp[VALUE]) 
                        ? wrappedComponentProp[VALUE].toJS() 
                        : wrappedComponentProp[VALUE];
                return newProps;
            }, {});

       return <WrappedComponent {...propsJS} />
   };
```

A HOC component (with the latest immutable.js using the isImmutable predicate):

```
import React from 'react';
import { isImmutable } from 'immutable';

export const toJS = (WrappedComponent) =>
   (wrappedComponentProps) => {
       const KEY = 0;
       const VALUE = 1;

       const propsJS = Object.entries(wrappedComponentProps)
            .reduce((newProps, wrappedComponentProp)  => {
                newProps[wrappedComponentProp[KEY]] = 
                    isImmutable(wrappedComponentProp[VALUE]) 
                        ? wrappedComponentProp[VALUE].toJS() 
                        : wrappedComponentProp[VALUE];
                return newProps;
            }, {});

       return <WrappedComponent {...propsJS} />
   };
```

How to use:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { toJS } from './to-js';

import DumbComponent from './dumb.component';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
       /**
       obj is an Immutable object in Smart Component, but it’s converted to a plain 
       JavaScript object by toJS, and so passed to DumbComponent as a pure JavaScript 
       object. Because it’s still an Immutable.JS object here in mapStateToProps, though, 
       there is no issue with errant re-renderings.
       */
       obj: getImmutableObjectFromStateTree(state)
   }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent));
```

There are a lot of links to move on in the Redux [immutable-js-best-practices](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#immutable-js-best-practices) documentation section.

Comment: question.. what's the double-asterisk?

`const **VALUE = 1;`

Comment: @HusseinDuvigneau thanks for the review. This should not be here and besides I found their entire example not working in the last version. I corrected my code

Answer (score 1):

If you use ImmutableJS with redux, you're whole app state is an immutable. In the `connect` function, use state.get("posts") to access to the `posts` state. Then you will have to use `get()` to access the `posts` state properties. Or you can use [toJs()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/toJS) to avoid having to manipulate immutable inside your component.